# How would I integrate input() within iterative loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner at python and wanted to have a crack at my first personal project which is a score calculator for a student's subjects. I wanted to run a for loop that asks the user to input their scores for each of the individual subjects through an input() within a for loop. However, it would only take a singular string argument.

```
scores = {}
total = 0
years = int(input("How subjects have you completed? "))
for sub in range(0, years):
    scores = input("Score for subject?",x)
    total += int(scores)
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You have made a good start, however you might want to consider having the user enter the subject followed by a score.  You should also consider the fact that users are known to make mistakes, so you should provide error checks to ensure they enter text when they are supposed to ; integers when they should; and float numbers when they should.  For example, years should be an integer, subject should be text, and score could be a float.

Comment: I note you did not mention which subjects.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep track of scores by subject and find total score then...

```py
subjects = dict( Math = 0, English = 0, Science = 0, History = 0 )

scores = dict()
total = 0
for sub in subjects.keys():
    score = input( f"Score for {sub}? >" )
    if score:
        total += int( score )
        scores[sub] = score

print( total )

for sub,tot in scores.items():
    if tot > 0:
        print( sub, tot )
```

Answer (score 0):

- The variable `x` never defined and used, just remove it may solve your problem.
- `scores` first defined as a dict, then you re-define it without using it.Remove it make code more clear.

code:

```
total = 0
years = int(input("How subjects have you completed? "))
for sub in range(years):
    scores = input("Score for subject?")
    total += int(scores)
print(total)
```

result:

```
How subjects have you completed? 5
Score for subject?1
Score for subject?2
Score for subject?3
Score for subject?4
Score for subject?5
15
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample:

1. `x` is an undefined variable.
2. `scores = {}` the 'scores' dictionary is useless as later you redefine it as a string.

Just removing the `,x` in line 5 will make the code execute properly.

```py
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in range(int(input("How many subjects have you completed? "))):
...     total += int(input("Score for subject? "))
...
How many subjects have you completed? 3
Score for subject? 70
Score for subject? 80
Score for subject? 90
>>> total
240
```